# JMeter Proxy server doesn't work (No Internet)

Tags: testing, proxy, jmeter, performance-testing

[enter image description here]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGP3y.jpg)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J33fg.jpg)I am an amateur in software testing I was trying to learn JMeter performance testing. I was trying to script record using proxy server. But after setting up proxy server whenever I start the record I can't access internet. It simply says "NO INTERNET". After disabling proxy server I can again access internet(Google Chrome). I tried both 8888 and 8080 port.

`your text`(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQhn2.png)
`your text`(https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbA0m.png)
`your text`(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VFwt.png)

Am I missing something? What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case you're behind a corporate proxy server, you need to [make JMeter aware of this server](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server) by passing the upstream proxy details via command-line arguments or system.properties file.

Also be aware of an alternative way of recording a JMeter test: [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates.

Comment: Although I can record the script using another browser (Edge)

Comment: But it shows an red alarm sign "Not secure" from advance option I can "continue to url"